# Google Sheets - Dynamic Hyperlink Formula with 2 Variables

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

How do you create a dynamic hyperlink with 2 or more variables? I know that this is the way to do it with one:

with the **A1** cell equaling "Google"

```
=HYPERLINK("https://twitter.com/"&A1, "Twitter Acc")
```

will result in https://twitter.com/Google

But if I want to do something like this:

with the **A2** cell equaling "photo"

```
=HYPERLINK("https://twitter.com/"&A1"/"&A2, "Twitter Acc Photo")
```

I would expect https://twitter.com/Google/photo. What I get however, is an **#ERROR** instead.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one `&` and you didn't concatenate properly: `&A1&"/"&A2` instead of `&A1"/"&A2`:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://twitter.com/"&A1&"/"&A2, "Twitter Acc Photo")
```

Or you can use [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en) if you don't want to use `&`:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://twitter.com/",A1,"/",A2),"Twitter Acc Photo")
```